# Action depends on two Event activations

Tags: .net, events, datagridview

Goal:
I want to set a Default Value in a DGV after a user clicked the "Add New Row - Button".

Problem:
I cannot set the `datacolumn.defaultvalue` in the .click event since the new column is not created yet.
I cannot set the `datacolumn.defaultvalue` in the datagridview.rowadded event since then, when I load the DGV it is trying to set the defaultvalue for every row in the dgv (I load my datasets from a sql server). But it should only add the default value for the new row added.

Solution:
I tried many events nothing works. Maybe it is possible to combine the events. Like 
if event 1 and event 2 then. But I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the `DataGridView.DefaultValuesNeeded` event and add your default values in the event handler.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link for example. But read the remarks section carefully as the behavior is different for each operating mode (Databound or virtual).

If new row is added using the underlying `DataTable` then set the default value as below.

```
DataTable table = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
if (table != null)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["columnName"] = defaultValue;
    table.Rows.Add(row);                
}
```

Comment: My problem is, 'Occurs when the user enters the row...'. When a user clicks the "Add new row" - Button this defaultvaluesneeded doesnt get fired because the user doesnt enter the row even though the cursour is in the first cell. So the user starts filling the cells and afterwards the program gives the error that not all default values are set.

Comment: @ruedi - If you set the currentcell to any of the new row cell it will mimic user selection. Is the DataGridView is in virtual mode?

Comment: I use databound. I tried BenutzerTabelle_SelectDataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows(DataGridView.NewRowIndex).Cells(0) already, but still the same error. It cannot save because default values are not set. Says to me the row selection is different from user selection... but i am by far not an expert.